# How to create DropDown list for editing data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have two partial views - one is for adding data, the other one is for editing.
One of the fields represents months, so for inserting that field I created a ViewBag with a for loop that populates it from 1 to 12. That works fine.

My problem is how to do that for editing? How can I create the same DropDown list that will show months for editing?

This is what I have for inserting:

In my controller:

```
var lMesec = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            lMesec.Add(i);

        }

ViewBag.listaMesec = new SelectList(lMesec);
```

In my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mesec, ViewBag.listaMesec as SelectList, "Izaberite mesec", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

When I am reading data for editing this is in my view:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mesec, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

How can I make this into DropDown list that can have values from 1-12?

I am reading data with SqlDataAdapter, so I have this value:

```
 model.mesec = dt.Rows[0][3] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][3]) : 0;
```

Comment: just use DropdownListFor in both scenarios, and have the viewbag values available in both scenarios. Is there some reason why doing that presents a difficulty?

Comment: yes, because when editing, there would at first not be the value that is at the time saved, but there will be shown at first value, in this case number 1

Comment: " because when editing, there would at first not be the value that is at the time saved"...you mean it is not setting the dropdown to display the selected value? Unless your model is not populated correctly, then that's impossible, sorry. DropdownListFor will take the value of `model.mesec` and try to match it with the value of one of the items in the SelectList. If it finds a match, then it will set that value as the selected option in the dropdown when the page is displayed. If there is no match, it will set the first item in the list as the selected item instead.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of paying attention. You are right, all I had to do was settin the dropdownlistfor. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple, and @ADyson provided it.
All I had to do was use the same DropDownListFor on the edit form, and defining that list in my edit part of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a form helper class. Something like [yourname].cs (suggest all form helpers in a formhelper folder for easy access/locating)

```
public static MvcHtmlString numberDropdownlistFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
         Dictionary<string, string> numberList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
           {"", "---DropDown Title---"}
          ,{"1", "one"}
          ,{"2", "two"}
          ,{"3", "three"}
          ,{"4", "four"}
          ,{"5", "five"}
          ,{"6", "six"}
          ,{"7", "seven"}
          ,{"8", "eight"}
          ,{"9", "nine"}
          ,{"10", "ten"}
          ,{"11", "eleven"}
          ,{"12", "twelve"}
         };
 return html.DropDownListFor(expression, new SelectList(numberList, "key", "value"), new { @class = "form-control" });
}
```

then in your form you will call the newly created ddl like:

```
@Html.numberDropdownlistFor(x => x.Number)
```

This has worked for me in the past but with significantly bigger drop down lists.
Hope this helps - also, swap numbers and their correlating spelled out versions